# SQL Server : Case return value in one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I am trying to achieve the red table. I am using the case function nevertheless it repeats itself to every place. So far I have Distinct, removed all possible duplicate columns.

What function should I use to have just one line? But I want those columns.

```
CASE WHEN Place = 'BEL' THEN Stock END AS BEL,
CASE WHEN Place = 'BIR' THEN Stock END AS BIR,
CASE WHEN Place = 'COR' THEN Stock END AS COR
```

Thank you

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ28M.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rco**strong text**ha.png

Comment: Smells of a bad database design, but without knowing what those acronyms stand for it's hard to say. And if those acronyms are *really* the column names, that is itself an issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation.  The general idea is:

```
select acct, doc, . . . sales, cost,
       max(bel), max(bir), . . 
from t
group by acct, doc, . . . sales, cost;
```

The `. . .` is for the other columns.